# How to extract a value constrained by generic parameter?

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's take this generic:

```js
type Option<V extends string | boolean | number = string> = {
  label: string
  value: V
}
```

I now want to get a type for all values that `option.value` can acquire - so `string | boolean | number`.

What I've tried

```js
// This evaluates to `string`, because no argument was provided, so default was used:
type T = Option["value"]
// This evaluates to `any`, since it was passed in
type T = Option<any>["value"]
// This doesn't even compile, but somehow results in "unknown"
type T = Option<unknown>["value"]
```

Is there some way to extract my desired type? :)

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve but does any of [these approaches](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7APAWAFBSgNSggA9gIUATAZykuACcEUBzKAHygCMkkAbCAQxRsoKAK4BbDhDpQAvDXqMW7LrwFD2YydOwA+OVADe2XD35SeALgUNmAbhNQAbvx6iI1vA6wBfb9lBIWHhkFAAmNAJiUgpqWltlTm4+QWEtKTp9eWMcKDMLa3ilb1wXNw98bz9sAPBoAEkUADNpOghyABU6sIM4RFQAbQAiMvchgF1vQIbm1vauoPk+0Iii5mFVFI0RCQzdYdGICbsgA) meet your requirements?

Comment: This would require some kind of higher-order type operations that don't exist in TypeScript; you can't query an arbitrary generic type for the constraints on its type parameters.  Anything I can think of to even begin would require you write out the constraints a second time.  Which defeats the purpose.  So the answer here is "no" although I don't know if there's authoritative documentation about that (absences of features aren't always documented).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it does fully address the question. I will just define the constraint as a separate type then. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting for completeness:

No, as of TypeScript 5.1 there is no way to query a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type for the [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on its type parameters.  That would require type-level support for manipulation of generic types, and this sort of higher-order or higher-[kinded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) generic typing is not part of the language.

I can't find a specific issue in GitHub that asks for this particular feature.  There are other  longstanding open feature requests that ask for various higher kinded types at the type level, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) asking for generic type parameters to themselves take type parameters (e.g., `type Foo<F<_>, T> = F<T>`), or [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) asking for existentially quantified generic type parameters (e.g., `type Bar = <exists T> {v: T, f: (v: T)=>void}`), or [microsoft/TypeScript#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) asking for universally quantified generic values other than functions (e.g., `type Baz = <forall T> {f1: (x: T)=>void, f2: (x: T)=>void}`).  It's not clear that any or all of these would be needed to give you the query you're looking for, but none of them are supported today so it's academic.  The language is currently not expressive enough.

You'll have to just write out your constraints multiple times, manually.